# How to load module at runtime in Node.js?

Tags: node.js

I have a Node.js service, let's call it ***Service A***. Users could visit my website via ***Service A***.

I would like to have the feature, that different users could see different things in my website. To achieve it, ***Service A*** should be able to execute different code scripts (node module) depend on the user's configuration.

Since the scripts (node module) are updated frequently, I don't want to store them in ***Service A***. So here I have a ***Service B***, the function of it is storing all the scripts (node module). ***Service A*** could send user's configuration to ***Service B***, ***Service B*** will return the corresponding script (node module) to ***Service A***. So in ***Service A*** I would like to have following code:

```
http.get('http://urlToServiceB?userConfig=' + userConfig, (resp) => {
    resp.on('data', (scriptInString) => {
        // Here I got the script in string, I would like to load the module from it.
        // Expect something like following:
        var moduleFromScript = myRequire(scriptInString);
        moduleFromScript.myfunction();
        ...
    });
})
```

How can I implement the *myRequire* function? Is there any open source libs? Thanks a lot!

Comment: So `scriptInString` is a string containing JavaScript code?

Comment: @FelixKling Yes, it is the .js file and it could be in any format.